# Anonymous Bug in Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am populating Recyclerview items by reading  Text (.txt) files from Raw 
Folder.It is populated as good.Having 10 Title.

When I click the 1st Title, the related data is shown in Next Activity through an Intent(Intent has value).

But when I click any RecyclerViewItem except 1st Title,Next Activity is opened,but respective data is not passed to next activity.

But in Adapter class,I could get the Title while Clicking it.

Even I have tried by using Listview but nothing worked...

Here is my Code:

**Adapter Text OnClickListener:**

```
holder.txtSong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                String forecast = (String) txtView.getText();
                Log.e("Position", String.valueOf(position) );
                Log.e("Position..1",forecast);

                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

**MainActivity:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.song_list_item);
        context = this;

        pref = this.context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String Song = i.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

        try {
            InputStream inputstream = getResources().getAssets().open(Song + ".txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));

            String m = reader.toString();
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            m = total.toString();

            textView.setText(m);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error" + ex);
        }
}
```

Your answer is more appreciated...

Comment: can you post your MainActivity class?

Comment: try with some name like  `i.putExtra("Title", forecast);` and  `String Song = i.getExtras().getString("Title");`

Comment: Okay..Let me do.But I have done the same as before.But nothing worked in my case. I ll try again @MD

Comment: ok Are you sure you got that String in `Adapter` class? or change  `String forecast = txtView.getText().toString();`

Comment: I am getting in Adapter class

Comment: 04-23 18:32:19.706 22308-22308/hitesh.androidjsonapp E/Position: 2 Proclaim Your awesome power

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110008/discussion-between-m-d-and-parama-sudha).

Comment: The above is the LogCat result of getting String.

Answer (score 1):

Just Try

```
Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
```

for recieving

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String Song = i.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

please try removing getExtras(); an use `getStringExtra();`